# Android Button background from style does not apply

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to setup style for Button, but from some unknown reasons attribute "background" from style is not applying. I want achieve a transparent rectangle button over arrow that is on lower layer.

I created style ButtonMorse:

```
<style name="ButtonMorse" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
        <item name="background">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

For comparison 1st button background attribute is set directly, not using style (works fine).

Layout code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUp0"
        android:layout_marginStart="525dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        android:onClick="buttonUp0Click"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/CharacterMorseTextView"
        android:id="@+id/character0"
        android:layout_marginStart="522dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp" />

    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonMorse"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDown0"
        android:layout_marginStart="525dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="525dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDown0Click"/>
```

Color:
`<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>`

Result:
[Result on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyLlo.png)

Comment: You're wrong, in style, put `android:background`, not `background`

Comment: Thanks @AnantaRaha , it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ananta commented - there was mistake in my style file. It should be:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
```

instead of:

```
<item name="background">@color/transparent</item>
```

Question closed.